# Error comes from float data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, floating-point

I have defined Latitude and Longitude in my database. Both are Float data type. I want to display the geo information on a map. My problem is when I use @Model (I am using Asp.net MVC and Razor syntax) to pass these information to varables. The code is

```
var latitude = @Model.Latitude;
var longitude = @Model.Longitude;
```

It showed me a curly red line behind each line. And when I hovered mouse there, it displayed like

```
Double?Dinner.Latitude
Double?Dinner.Longitude
```

I dont have any idea about it. Then I tried to cast the datatype like

```
var latitude = (double)(@Model.Latitude);
var latitude = (double)(@Model.Longitude);
```

The red curly line did dispear but it showed me

```
"Undefined Double"
```

Who knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var latitude = Model.Latitude`? I don't think the `@` symbol is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on a razor scope, you do not need to use `@` keyworkd to access server-side values. Just try to open a razor block and set the variables, try something this:

```
@{

  var latitude = (double)Model.Latitude;
  var longitude= (double)Model.Longitude;

}
```

And then to show it, use the `@` razor keyworkd:

```
<p>@latitude</p>
<p>@longitude</p>
```

you also can format this values using `ToString()` method from double type:

```
<p>@latitude.ToString("0.000")</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.Latitude);
decimal longitude= Convert.ToDecimal(Model.Longitude);
```